# WebClient returns HTTP 404 for a valid URI

Tags: c#, webclient

I want to get html of a page with source code:

```
try {
  var webContent = "";
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) {
    client.Headers.Add (HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");

    webContent = client.DownloadString (@"http://localhost:8080/account/login");
  }
} catch (WebException ex) {
  var responseText = string.Empty;
  var responseStream = ex.Response?.GetResponseStream ();

  if (responseStream != null) {
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (responseStream)) {
      responseText = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    }
  }
}
```

I can get content of http://localhost:8080/.
But with http://localhost:8080/account/login, it returns "Cannot GET /account/login". I can browse to this url by browser.

How can I get html of http://localhost:8080/account/login using WebClient?

Thanks,

Comment: Because /account/login is `POST` action no?

Comment: It is a GET action.

Comment: I can fix my issue. Beside UserAgent, I need supply Accept in request's header. For example: client.Headers.Add("Accept", @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");

Answer (score 1):

Open Chrome, and Developer Tools (press F12).
Open Network tab.

Navigate to http://localhost:8080/account/login

You may see a redirect or 2 (check 302). The pages underneath may help you to find out which page is being redirected.

You can also test using powershell

```
wget http://localhost:8080/account/login
```